# Watin HTML Source Not Updating

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to use Watin to automate soundclouds API as I need to convert a range of user id's into usernames.

I'm getting the json result displayed fine in IE and the browser is looping through exactly as planned.

I can get the html.tostring() and write it to a file 100% fine for the first user. However when the loop continues, the html.tostring() seems not to update and just replicates the first users data. (remember that the actual browser is looping through the users fine)

```
IE ie = new IE();


while (counter <= counterMax)
{

    ie.GoTo("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/" + counter + ".json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID");

    Console.WriteLine(ie.Html.ToString());               
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\path\\" + counter + ".txt");          
    file.WriteLine(ie.Html.ToString());
    file.Close();

    counter++;


}


ie.Close();
```

I cant figure it out, if I close and reopen the browser with code in each iteration of the loop it works as planned, but this will take far too long for the amount of data I need to use.

Comment: Seems a lot to create a new file for each user, is this required?

Comment: I cant see how it would be to do with the file object as its also being duplicated in the console.writeline(), tested anyway with no luck. And the new file is not required ive just used it while i try figure this issue out.

Comment: @ Scott Stevens does it take too much time because the browser is running(Where you can see it) while it scrapes the data? You could always run this in background mode and move IE ie = new IE(); inside the loop.

Comment: the browser is running yes. Even when hidden however the increase in time is atleast 10x more than without needing to reopen the instance.

Comment: On my system pointing at an .asp page instead of .json yields expected results.   I started counter at 51 and maxCounter at 53.  ie.GoTo("http://www.asp-dev.com/main.asp?page="+counter);  Possibly a JSON related issue?

Comment: Possibly, i decided to stop using watin for this project as i could not solve the issue. Thanks for all the hellp anyway guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\path\\" + counter + ".txt", true);
```

You need to enable append so the stream can write to the file each time it iterates through the loop.

Comment: Its actually making a new file for each user intentionally at the moment, im aware of how the file writing can be improved - i just find it easier to debug with them in separate files.

Comment: I see that now. Counter++ in the filename. Have you tried creating a new IE instance each time? That may be your problem since strings are immutable.

Comment: yes and creating a new instance each time works perfectly, but on the scale i need to do this on it will increase run time too much.